# Java overriding hashCode doesn't show effect

Tags: java, overriding, hashcode

```
public class mainB {
    public mainB(){
        System.out.println("java".hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 4;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new  mainB();
    }
}
```

I'm **overriding the hashCode** method but when I run app **it doesn't show 4**. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You're simply doing it wrong. `"java".hashCode()` simply gets the hash code of `String` object. If you want to get the correct hash code:

1) Override `hashCode` method.

2) Create an **instance** of class with overriden method.

3) Call `hashCode`.

Being honest overriding `hashCode` might be dangerous and result in efficiency decrease. This is why you shouldn't override it if you're not sure that you're doing it right. When you are not certain the best way is always to generate it in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse) which will do it properly.

Answer (score 4):

You're overriding `mainB` hashcode function but you use `String` hashcode one when using `"java".hashcode()`.

To use your function you should do :

```
new mainB().hashcode()
```

Comment: Also "java" is temporary then garbage collected so you cannot use same again am i right?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık Well String hashcode should be consistent on character that compose the String. So you will have the same. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `hashCode()` method for class `mainB`. So when you create an object of this class and invoke `hashCode()` you will get 4 like:

```
mainB myObject = new mainB();
System.out.println(" HashCode = " + myObject.hashCode());
```

And when you write following:

```
System.out.println("java".hashCode());
```

you are invoking `hashCode()` method on a `String` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
public mainB(){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing hash code of string that contains word `"java"`. 
Change your implementation to

`System.out.println(hashCode());`

and your `hashCode()` will be called.